# How to implement "select all" check box in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I also have an HTML page with multiple checkboxes by using `AngularJs`.

I need one more checkbox with the name "select all". When I select this checkbox all checkboxes in the HTML page must be selected. How can I do this?

My check box situation is like this:

```
<input id="check_0_0_1"  type="checkbox">
<input id="check_0_1_1"  type="checkbox">
<input id="check_0_1_2"  type="checkbox">
<input id="check_0_2_1"  type="checkbox">
//and so on
```

I've already read the page below, but I still don't know how to implement it with AngularJS

Comment: Any angular code to share with us ?

Comment: Please read how to create a [mcve] and add the missing information to your Post by editing it :) If you haven't read [ask] yet i recommend to do so :) I highly recommend to follow the 2 guides i linked as the people on SO are more likely to answer questions when the posts follow these guides. What i'm missing in particular is - What have u tried so far? What errors/problems do you face? Do you may have codesnippets that show what you tried so far? Welcome to StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this code:

```
<form id="selectionForm">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" >Select all
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="selectAll || option1" ng-init="option1=true" ng-model="option1">Option 1
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="selectAll">Option 2
</form>
```